# Moving directory from PC to server with Bash, SCP, and SSH

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, ssh, scp

I am attempting to move my Flask Application directory from my PC to my Ubuntu server (hosted on Linode) using the Ubuntu Bash terminal (I'm running Windows).

When I run this:

```
scp -r C:\my_application myc@(my server IP):~/
```

I get this error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname c: Name or service not known
```

When I tried adding ssh in front like:

```
scp -r C:\my_application ssh myc@(my server IP):~/
```

I get:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname c: Name or service not known
ssh: No such file or directory
```

I also tried doing it from desktop like:

```
scp -r \desktop\my_application myc@(my server IP):~/
scp -r /desktop/my_application myc@(my server IP):~/
```

to which I get, respectively:

```
desktopmy_application: No such file or directory
/desktop/my_application: No such file or directory
```

I am not quite sure what the issue is, as I can easily log into my server just using `ssh myc@(my server IP)`. My server is there and I can ssh into it no problem, but it won't let me move the directory.

My question is, how can I successfully move my file directory onto my server for that user?

Comment: I assume that `myc@(my seriver ip)` is just psuedo code to mask your local details. Your Q will be clearer if you use a dummy IP address. any address in the 192.168.*.* is a local only address and should not have any security issues for you to include that in your Q. Its alos possible that using `~` instead of `$HOME` may be confusing things. When you're trying debug a problem don't rely on short cuts. Spell things out explicitly and as briefly as possible. Your first form of the `scp` cmd is the correct one, but you should confirm you have `ssh` access ....

Comment: with the correct password, and again, by the simplest means possible, i.e. `ssh myc@192.168.4.5` for instance. Once that is working, then you can debug the `scp` command with confidence. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. That user definitely has ssh access, as I can log into my server using that user with `ssh` and no password required. I am still getting the could not resolve hostname issue, and I appreciate you clarifying the first one is the correct one.

Comment: so it is the `c:` part that is tripping things up? Try `scp -r /c/my_application ...`  I think that is you key Question. try your search-fu for `Windows Bash drive letters` and other such related topics. Otherwise I'm out of ideas right now. Maybe tomorrow. Good luck! ;-)

Comment: OR just to get it working, `cd c:\my_application; scp -r * myc@192.168.4.6`.should work. Going to bed. Good luck.

Comment: Yikes, it's not even letting me navigate to directory as you suggested. I am a windows guy and I admit I am a bit lost using this Bash shell. I am sort of stuck at this point. Thanks for your help thus far. If it helps at all, the genesis of this problem is I was attempting to follow this tutorial and am getting stuck at (29:56, where my issue arises)  https://youtu.be/goToXTC96Co?t=1796 Maybe the problem is I'm not using a virtual environment? But what does that have to do with scp? Does that sound possible?

Comment: OK, I think I got confused. You're using the Bash shell for Windows 10? Do we know if `/c/` works instead of `c:` ? if so, try `cd /c/my_application ; scp -r * myc@192.168.7.3` ? Any better, and sorry for the confusion. Good luck.

Comment: Nothing is working here, thanks again for the help. I'm thinking about just trying WinSCP here as I have no other options at this point. I've probably tried ~50 different commands with all types of slashes etc...

Comment: Can you get a local power user to check out your situation? It should work just like shown on the youtube you referenced. But yes, go for `winscp` and hopefully that will work. Good luck!

Comment: Strangely, I went back to check the tutorial, and It seems I successfully used scp previously at the 18:00 mark in that same video. But you may be correct about contacting someone, because even `winscp` isn't working it's telling me "No supported authentication methods available(server sent:publickey)". Anyway, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that scp considers C a hostname because there is a : character which scp itself uses to delimiter the parts, i.e. host:path If you use a relative path for the source then it will work.